# rmarkdown render to use the same environment as server

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to generate a report. The data for this report is generated from  a function that is called when a user uploads the input file. So the code example is:

app.R:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput('fileInput_pd', 'add the file', accept = '.xlsm'),
    downloadButton('report', 'Generate report')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    observe({
      if(is.null(input$fileInput_pd)) {
        return()
      } else {
        wr <- function() { variri <- 5}
        wr() }
    })
    
    
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "teste.html",
      content = function(file) {
        # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
        # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
        # can happen when deployed).
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "teste.Rmd")
        file.copy("teste.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
        
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

teste.Rmd

````
---
title: "teste"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
print(variri)
  
```
````

However, when I try to generate the report, it is giving me an error saying

```
Quitting from lines 11-13 (teste.Rmd) 

Warning: Error in print: object 'variri' not found.
```

How can I connect my report with the varibles generated in `wr()` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can only use the same environment when creating reports with markdown with a parameterised setup. This would require some changes to the downloadhandler() and the YAML header in the markdown using the following setup found here.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html